# Article défini / indéfini

Tags: grammaire, articles

Imaginez la situation où je rencontre mon ami dans une rue. Je lui donne un livre. Nous n'avons jamais parlé de ce livre avant.

Je lui dis

> Tiens UN livre

Dois-je utiliser l'article indéfini, parce que ce livre n'a pas été mentionné.

> Tiens LE livre

Ou dois-je utiliser l'article défini, car je lui donne le livre concrète?

Comment: C'est la même différence que "the" et "a" en anglais non ? Mais "Tiens UN livre" et "Tiens LE livre" sonnent faux en français. Cela doit dépendre de pourquoi vous rencontrez votre ami dans la rue, et pourquoi vous lui donnez ce livre ? Qu'auriez vous dit en anglais ?

Comment: Peut-être, on aura dit "Here's a book".

Comment: on mettra également une virgule après "tiens", à moins qu'on veuille qu'il s'y agrippe et non pas simplement qu'il le prenne.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dans la réalité, il n'y a pas besoin de toujours désigner dans le discours l'objet des articles définis. Si je t'invite à prendre un livre, en général, je te le montre et ça suffit pour clairement l'identifier.

Si tu montres le livre, si tu le tiens déjà dans la main, etc, on préfèrera dire :

> Tiens le livre

Car sans l'avoir dit, nous savons tous les deux de quel livre nous parlons.

S'il n'est pas possible d'identifier le livre (s'il est dans un sac, par exemple), on peut dire :

> Tiens un livre

**ATTENTION :**

A l'oral :

> Tiens, un livre

Peut parfois signifier quelque chose de totalement différent.
*"Tiens, un livre"* : c'est un livre que je viens de trouver, par terre, que je ne connais probablement pas.
Le verbe "*tenir*" exprime la surprise, la découverte, l'intérêt :

> Tiens, j'ai lu un article hier sur le projet de loi ...

"Tiens" sert à capter l'attention.

### Autres options :

Si le livre est clairement défini, ou qu'on le montre d'une manière quelconque, on utilise souvent l'adjectif démonstratif "*ce*"

> Tiens ce livre

Si on souhaite donner, offrir quelque chose à quelqu'un, on utilise aussi le verbe "*prendre*"

> Prends ce livre

Answer (score 2):

Puisque que vous n'en avez jamais parlé auparavant, la phrase correcte est la première avec l'article indéfini :

> Tiens un livre.

On pourrait utiliser l'article défini dans le cas où on ajoute un commentaire, du genre :

> Tiens, voici le livre qui m'a tenu éveillé toute la nuit.

Comment: Dans la pratique, la phrase "Tiens un livre" ne s'emploiera jamais, sauf en y ajoutant la virgule suggérée par Anne Aunyme, car cela signifie que l'interlocuteur n'a aucun moyen de situer le livre dont on lui parle, donc l'expression "Tiens un livre" ne tient pas, il faut nécessairement y ajouter un complément.

Comment: @BBBreiz Nous sommes dans le domaine de la conversation donc on ne peut pas évoquer la virgule qui est un signe écrit. À l'oral il faut parler de pause et de contexte.