# Ce n'est pas une clim, c'est un chauffage

Tags: usage

Je voudrais savoir si la phrase suivante est correcte en ce qui concerne l'utilisation des articles, et si elle se dirait couramment :

> Ce n'est pas **une** clim, c'est **un** chauffage...

Je vous donne le contexte : j'appuie sur le bouton qui est censé déclencher le dispositif qui souffle de l'air frais mais mon interlocuteur trouve qu'il souffle de l'air chaud.

Dans le même ordre d'idées :

> J'ai acheté **un** chauffage.
>   J'ai deux chambres et il n'y en a qu'une où il y a **un** chauffage.

Comment: Sur quoi pose la question ? Toutes les phrases données sont correctes, pourquoi les articles indéfinis sont en gras ?

Comment: Oui, tout à fait correcte... A noter que parfois de tels dispositifs peuvent faire les deux (chaud ou froid) et sont souvent appelés dans ce cas-là "Climatisation réversible"

Comment: Cette question n'est pas très claire et mériterait d'être reformulée. La question potte-telle sur le mot « chauffage  » ? La phrase  « Ce n'est pas une clim, c'est un chauffage » est tout à fait possible. Pour ce qui est des sens du mot chauffage, on les trouve très facilement dans un dictionnaire.

Comment: Ma question porte effectivement sur les articles,  je pensais qu'il fallait dire plutôt :  cela ne rafraîchit pas , cela chauffe ou : ce n'est pas la clim, c'est le chauffage.

Comment: Et pour la phrase suivante : je pensais à : " j'ai acheté un appareil de chauffage ou, en précisant : un convecteur, un poêle , un radiateur etc..

Comment: Et pour la dernière phrase : " ...il n'y en a qu'une où il y a un chauffage..."

Comment: La raison de mes tâtonnements : on dit , et là-dessus, je n'ai aucun doute ,  "dans ma nouvelle maison, on n'a pas encore installé LE chauffage.

Comment: En Anglais ça donnerait également dans un exemple différent: "it's not a car, it's a truck", ça sonne juste je trouve.

Comment: @prinver Dans ce cas tu parles d'un chauffage spécifique, celui de ta maison, tu ne fais pas de généralité. Par exemple tu pourras demander à quelqu'un "Où est-ce que tu as garé **la** voiture", parce que l'on sait de quelle voiture il s'agit, en revanche tu diras d'une façon générale "Comment gare-t-on **une** voiture ?".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Article défini / indéfini](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/18776/article-d%c3%a9fini-ind%c3%a9fini)

Answer (score 1):

Since clim is feminine, and chauffage is masculine, your articles are perfectly correct.